# Changing file names based on enclosing directory

Tags: files, rename, wildcards

Excuse the newby question but I have a number of unique directories which each contain a single file of a generic name.

[image]

What I would like to do is to move nd rename the files into a single directory

Preferably using wildcards but I guess you could also generate a list and cycle through it.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to do something like this,

```
for d in ${PATH_OF_YOUR_DIRECTORY}/*/ ; do
    mv ${d}index.html ${PATH_WHERE_YOU_HAVE_TO_MOVE}/$(basename ${d}).html
done
```

Comment: Is this a shell script or can it be entered directly in the terminal?

Comment: you can use it in both the ways dear ! try it @AusS2000

Comment: Cheers, that hit the spot!

(I was having a problem with the $ at the start of the path as my paths were absolute. I removed them and it worked)

Comment: I'm glad !! keep scripting !!

Comment: Hi @AusS2000 *if* the answer solved your problem, as you indicated, please consider to accept the answer (tick the big "V" below the up/down arrows on the left). It is the appropriate way to indicate the answer worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from the question *how* the files should be renamed, so I'm going to assume that they should be renamed by appending the name of their original directory to their original name.

The code below assumes that your working directory holds the subdirectories and each subdirectory has the `index.html` file, as shown in the question.  The `index.html` files will be moved to a new directory called `allfiles`.

```bash
mkdir allfiles || exit

for pathname in */index.html
do
    mv -- "$pathname" "allfiles/${pathname%/index.html}-index.html"
done
```

The `pathname` variable will hold pathnames like `A-Dwelling-Place/index.html`, and the parameter expansion `${pathname%/index.html}` would remove the `/index.html` bit from the end of that pathname.

You could instead iterate over the directories rather than the files,

```
mkdir allfiles || exit

for dirname in */
do
    mv -- "$dirname"/index.html "${dirname%/}-index.html"
done
```

In this case, the `dirname` variable would hold pathnames like `A-Dwelling-Place/`, and `${dirname%/}` would delete that trailing slash character.